# Umlauts and slices

Tags: go

I'm having some trouble while reading a file which has a fixed column length format. Some columns may contain umlauts.

Umlauts seem to use 2 bytes instead of one. This is not the behaviour I was expecting. Is there any kind of function which returns a substring? Slice does not seem to work in this case.

Here's some sample code:

http://play.golang.org/p/ZJ1axy7UXe

```
umlautsString := "Rhön"
fmt.Println(len(umlautsString))
fmt.Println(umlautsString[0:4])
```

Prints:

```
5
Rhö
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In go, a slice of a string counts bytes, not [runes](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Rune_literals). This is why `"Rhön"[0:3]` gives you `Rh` and the first byte of `ö`.

Characters encoded in UTF-8 are represented as runes because UTF-8 encodes characters in more than one 
byte (up to four bytes) to provide a bigger range of characters.

If you want to slice a string with the `[]` syntax, convert the string to `[]rune` before.
Example ([on play](http://play.golang.org/p/0NNTeQG5jr)):

```
umlautsString := "Rhön"
runes = []rune(umlautsString)
fmt.Println(string(runes[0:3])) // Rhö
```

Noteworthy: [This golang blog post about string representation in go](http://blog.golang.org/strings).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I didn't realize it was possible to convert to `[]rune` - this will allow me to clean up some of my recent code.

Comment: “UTF-8 characters are encoded as runes” makes no sense at all. Could you clarify, rewrite or delete it?

Comment: @rightfold You're being rude. It has made sense to at least 9 other people, so deleting the answer is out of question. You could've asked nicely for a clarification, but in this case it seems as you were too lazy to follow either of the links nemo posted, which both explain in detail what a rune ist.

Comment: @x3ro I know what a rune is and I know what an encoding is and the part I quoted makes no sense (not just to me, but in general). There is no such thing as "UTF-8 characters." Moreover, I never said nemo should clarify, rewrite or delete _the whole answer_, only _the part I quoted_.

Comment: @rightfold: I'd ask you to take a look at [RFC 3629](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3629#section-3) to re-evaluate whether or not "UTF-8 characters" exist. And how can you assume that the accepted answer which was upvoted 10 times has parts that do not make sense _in general_? That seems a little far fetched.

Comment: @x3ro I don't assume it, I raise it.

Comment: @rightfold Granted, 'encoded' is ambiguous. Fixed that.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert `string` to `[]rune` and work with it:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
  umlautsString := "Rhön"

  fmt.Println(len(umlautsString))

  subStrRunes:= []rune(umlautsString)

  fmt.Println(len(subStrRunes))

  fmt.Println(string(subStrRunes[0:4]))
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/__WfitzMOJ

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the `utf8string` package:

```
package main
import "golang.org/x/exp/utf8string"

func main() {
   s := utf8string.NewString("")
   // example 1
   n := s.RuneCount()
   println(n == 5)
   // example 2
   t := s.Slice(0, 2)
   println(t == "")
}
```

https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/utf8string